# Why can't I adopt kids in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I killed Grelod and bought a house but I never got the letter from Constance? Why?

Comment: Do they have somewhere to sleep in the house? You'll need to purchase a child's bed for them to sleep in first.

Comment: Did you finished the quest Aventus Aretino gave you? I received the letter just after that, even though I don't have any house yet.

Answer (score 4):

You must own a house that has at least one child bed in order to adopt.   If your only home is Breezehome, for example, then you would need to remove the Alchemist's room addon by purchasing the Child's Room addon from Proventus Avenicci.